# Keep tree of divs top-aligned, not nest-level-aligned

Tags: html, css, tree

I think what I'm trying to do is best explained by example, so see http://jsfiddle.net/56E4Y/2/.

I want the divs to all be aligned at the top of their mutual container, not aligned at the top of the other divs at the same nesting-level as themselves.

This works if I make .col float left, but that makes the rows reflow which I do not want. I want the rows to stay intact and be viewed via horizontal-scrolling.

Also, if somebody knows of a lightweight library for making and manipulating such html trees please let me know. My use case involves only insertions at arbitrary leaf nodes, so that's all I really care about performance-wise. The only libraries I could find were for the [other kind](https://code.google.com/p/dynatree) of tree. (More like a drill-down menu than a traditional tree.)

Source of the jsfiddle:

html

```
<div id="tree"></div>
```

js (just builds a tree into #tree)

```
var data = [[],[[]],[]];
var tree_area = document.getElementById('tree');
function buildTree(array, node) {
    var msg = document.createElement('div');
    msg.textContent = 'foo';
    msg.className = 'node';
    node.appendChild(msg);

    var row = document.createElement('div');
    row.className = 'row';
    node.appendChild(row);

    array.forEach(function(child) {
        var col = document.createElement('div');
        col.className = 'col';
        row.appendChild(col);

        buildTree(child, col);
    });
}
buildTree(data, tree_area);
```

css

```
div {
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#tree {
    width: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#tree .col {
    min-width: 100px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1);
    display: inline-block;
}
#tree .row {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#tree .node {
    display: block;
    background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.1);
    width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Like a multi-level vertical navbar?

Comment: Not quite, because all the levels are expanded at once, and the upper-items are horizontally shifted to make room for the full explosion of the subtrees and still be aligned with their respective subtrees. Add more [[[[[],[[]]]],[],[],[[[[[]],[]]]]]] to the data in the jsfiddle to see what I mean.

Comment: That is EXTREMELY imaginative - congratulations! I put vertical-align: top in the tree .col, added some extra []s, and updated your fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/56E4Y/1/. But I wonder if you're looking for something more. Probably not that simple.

Comment: Ah yes, that's what I was looking for, thanks! If you want to put `vertical-align: top;` on .col in an answer I'll mark it as correct and upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HERE is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/56E4Y/1/).

CSS

```
#tree .col {
    min-width: 100px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1);
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Glad I could help. Best of luck!